# Not showing Test code coverage on developer console

Tags: developer-console

I ran the test classes from developer console but it didnt not show me the lines which are covered. Whenever we run the test classes in developer console it highlights the the lines which are covered and which are not covered in different colors. I cleared test data,Compiled all classes and then again ran test classes but it didnt work. In Code Coverage menu i am just getting one option that is 'None'. Please suggest..

Comment: I believe sometimes it has glitches. You can try using mavenmate's plugin for sublime to run tests there, looks like mavenmate's test execution always shows coverage correctly

Comment: @Patlatus could you provide steps or may be help link of how to use it? Is it for IDE .. Thanks

Comment: Download and install MavensMate, then from within Sublime Text click `MavensMate > Unit Testing > Show Apex Code Coverage For This Apex Class`

Comment: Force.com IDE for Eclipse - run all tests will also give you code coverage

Comment: In case someone ends up here after Winter 16 upgrade - with Winter 16, there is a known issue that means you need to run the tests with the new "always run tests asynchronously" checkbox set to true in order to see code coverage...

Comment: Thanks @BritishBoyinDC, I had same issue and fix provided worked and saved lot of time

Comment: I provided one solution at https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/88511/not-showing-test-code-coverage-on-developer-console/332433#332433

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Go to the 'Apex Test Execution'and in option select list deselect the 'Store Only Aggregated Code Coverage' checkbox. [image]

Answer (score 8):

It appears that in latest Winter 2016 upgrade a bug was introduced where code coverage line highlights are missing from the Salesforce Developer Console

[image: salesforce-code-coverage-highlight-missing-fix]

You can get them back by selecting the 'Test > Always Run Asynchronously' checkbox and re-running your test.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your test class is covering the targeted class for which you have written the unit test methods.

`none` in top left dropdown is only displayed if there is no test method associated with the class which you have opened in dev console.

[image]

Comment: i ran the same test methods in eclipse, it was covering that class.

Answer (score 1):

For my case, for it to calculate, I had to launch the test class via build > Develop >Apex Test Execution. Then from the same screen, click on the developer console button.

Answer (score 1):

The following solved the problem for me I hope it helps you as well:

- Try to create a test suits in eclipse by going to: File > New > Apex
  Test Suite
- The "Create New Apex Test Suite" pop-up window should open up
- Now select the project you are working on
- In the text input box that is labeled "Apex Test Suite Properties",
  insert an arbitrary name for your test suite
- Click on Next and from the list of classes, select all the test
  classes that you need to run together (it can be just one class)
- Click Finish
- Now from "Run" menu select "Run Configurations" and the window will
  pop up
- You should see three tabs called "Project", "Test", and "Common",
  select "Test"
- now in the Test tab under "Select one or more test suites" section
  click on "Use suite" checkbox
- you should see the name of the test suite you just created (there
  might be other test suites there)
- click on the checkbox next to the name of the test suite that you
  created and want to run
- Finnaly click on "Apply" then click on "Run", and it will run the
  test suite and now you should see the test coverage and results in
  the "Apex Test Results" tab (I'm assuming you already know how to
  access this tab)

Answer (score 0):

The following solved this for me.
I had created some test accounts but forgot to match the name to my query used in creating the controller. It took a while to spot that I wasn't creating the controller and, therefore, not testing my class.

```
Account a1;
List<Account> lstAccs = [select id,name Account where name = 'A test account'];
List<Account> result = new List<Account>();
if (lstAccs .size()>0){
   a1 = lstAccs [0];
   ApexPages.StandardController theCont = new ApexPages.StandardController(a1);
   myExtControllerClass theContExt = new myExtControllerClass (theCont);
   result = myExtControllerClass.getResultOrSomeSuchMethod();
}
```

If I hadn't also created the account in setup, it wouldn't calculate any code coverage.

```
Account anAcc1 = new Account(name='A test account');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try recompiling all Apex classes.

If an Apex class is deleted (such as by someone else doing code cleanup) but the deleted class is still referenced by some other class, then Salesforce will not give you code coverage no matter what settings you toggle. Compiling all classes from the "Apex Classes" page in Setup can help you spot broken references like this. The compilation would fail and state which classes need fixed.

Just to be safe, I cleared the test execution cache after I got the compilation to succeed. After that, I was able to get code coverage again.