# No code coverage in sandbox and partial sandbox before preparing changeset

Tags: apex, code-coverage, change-set, test-setup

we have developed one solution in `Salesforce` in the `developer sandbox` the solution contains the `Apex Class`,`Trigger`, `Custom Objet` and `LWC`. Eventually, We are planning to release this solution as a changeset in the `production environment`. As it contains `Apex Class` and `Trigger` majorly, we need to create `Test classes` as well. But somehow when we are creating `Test Classes` in our `sandbox` or `partial sanbox` we are not able to view the `code coverage` even the test passes successfully.

1. Following are the `Apex Test Execution Options` set in both `Sandbox` and `Partial Sandbox`

[image]

2. I tried by clearing the test history too but no luck
3. Here is the code of `Test Class` and `OutboundDictionary` is the class name

   @isTest
   public  class OutboundDictionaryTest {

   ```
    @TestSetup
    static void makeData(){

        List<sObject> csvMappingList = Test.loadData(CSVSFMapping__c.SObjectType, 'CSVMappingFile');
        List<Account> accounts = new List<Account>();
        for(Integer i =0;i<5;i++){

            Account acc = new Account();
            acc.FirstName = 'First Name '+i;
            acc.LastName='Last Name '+i;
            acc.PersonEmail='accountinfo'+i+'@gmail.com';
            accounts.add(acc);
        }

        insert accounts;
        List<Opportunity> opptyList = new List<Opportunity>();


        for(Integer i =0;i<5;i++){

            Opportunity oppty = new Opportunity();
            oppty.accountId = accounts[i].Id;
            oppty.Address_Country__c = 'Canada';
            oppty.Institution_Type__c ='College';
            oppty.Citizenship_Status__c ='Canadian Citizen';
            oppty.CloseDate=Date.today();
            oppty.Country_of_Citizenship__c='Canada';
            oppty.Date_of_Birth__c =Date.newInstance(1985, 1, 17);
            oppty.Email_Address__c='opptyinfo'+i+'@gmail.com';
            oppty.Expected_Start_Date__c=Date.today();
            oppty.Gender__c ='Female';
            oppty.Media_Group__c='Co-enrolment';
            oppty.Media_SubGroup__c='Academy of Design Sign';
            oppty.Name ='oppty name '+i;
            oppty.StageName='Applicant';
            oppty.Telephone__c='909090909'+i;
            opptyList.add(oppty);
        }

        insert opptyList;


        List<SyncInfo__c> syncInfoList = new List<SyncInfo__c>();
        for(Integer i=0;i<opptyList.size()-1;i++){

            SyncInfo__c syncInfo = new SyncInfo__c();
            syncInfo.ObjectId__c=opptyList[i].Id;
            syncInfo.ObjectName__c='Opportunity';
            syncInfo.Status__c = 'IDLE';
            syncInfo.EventType__c='UPDATED';

            syncInfoList.add(syncInfo);


        }

        insert syncInfoList;
    }

    @isTest
    static void testOutbound(){

        List<Account> accounts = [SELECT ID FROM Account];
        List<Opportunity> oppty = [SELECT ID FROM Opportunity];




        OutboundDictionary outbound = new OutboundDictionary();
        outbound.addHeader();



   }
   ```

   }

0% code coverage

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Goto setup -> Develop -> Apex Test Execution and click the Options button.

Make sure "Store Only Aggregated Code Coverage" is UNCHECKED

OR

please check

[Not showing Test code coverage on developer console](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/88511/not-showing-test-code-coverage-on-developer-console)

Comment: It's already deselected see the screenshot in the question

Comment: I enabled it and the disabled it and now it is working